# CGAL::Surface_mesh Create surface mesh when number of vertices and faces are known

Tags: c++, cgal

I would like to ask if it is possible to optimize Surface mesh creation of CGAL in my code?
In the following loops I am just adding vertices and faces from a flat array of double representing vertices and int array of face ids.

Do I need somehow to reserve memory for faster conversion since number of vertices and faces is already known? And in my workflow it will never change.

```
CGAL::Surface_mesh<CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel::Point_3> mesh1;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_coord_mesh1; i++ ) {
   mesh1.add_vertex (CGAL::Epick::Point_3 (coord_mesh1[3 * i], coord_mesh1[3 * i + 1], coord_mesh1[3 * i + 2]));
}


for ( size_t i = 0; i < n_faces_mesh1; i++ ) {
    mesh1.add_face (CGAL::SM_Vertex_index (faces_mesh1[3 * i + 0]), CGAL::SM_Vertex_index (faces_mesh1[3 * i + 1]), CGAL::SM_Vertex_index (faces_mesh1[3 * i + 2]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Surface_mesh::reserve()`, as in the doc, here:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh.html#a2172cdbebc27ecf4ca36ac050aad11b8